# Can't get py2app to compile my python code. Feels like I'm getting close, but

Tags: python, compiler-errors, py2app

My python code  has a half dozen GUI screens, but all pretty basic stuff:  text, buttons, and such. It consists of 6 modules, and uses a dozen-ish data files.  The data files are also pretty plain.    I have  3 types:  txt, csv, png.  It has only few import requirements:  PySimpGUI, csv, re, and unicode (since it has includes non-English letters.)

To get familiar with py2app and to validate my install,   I first made a "Hello World!" program, basically just printing that line to a console.  That compiled both in the "alias mode"  in the stand alone app mode.  I could double-click of the app icon it produced and it ran correctly.  Then I tried a very simple GUI, a one line program that used my imported PySimpleGUI package.   Again this was a very simple program: just a little popup window with an OK button.  Push the button and the window closes and the program quits.  Aagain, that worked perfectly, both in the "alias" mode and a fully compiled, stand alone.    Having had those successes, I next tried my program.

When I run py2app on my setup.py file in the alias mode, again, the version py2app created works perfectly:  no error messages, and my program runs and behaves exactly as expected.  All of my GUI screens, and al their various buttons work correctly.   But when I do the final step, of compiling the standalone app, I get a flurry of error messages that I don't understand, and the compiled version won't run.

The error log, which emerges after a long log of stuff ahead of it, looks like thi:

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
stripping saved 0 bytes (15969600 / 15969600)
checking for any import problems
Modules not found (unconditional imports):

- _gdbm (dbm.gnu)
- _overlapped (asyncio.windows_events)
- com (com.sun.jna)
- com.jna (com.sun)
- com.sun (com.sun.jna.platform)
- ordereddict (pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing)
- win32com (win32com)
- win32com.shell (win32com.shell)
- win32com.shellcon (win32com.shell)

Modules not found (conditional imports):

- StringIO (pkg_resources._vendor.six)
- _manylinux (pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.tags)
- com (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
- com.sun.jna (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
- com.sun.jna.platform (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
- pep517 (importlib.metadata)
- win32com (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
- win32com.shell (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)

Suggestions of what to do next?  As I said, I'm a rookie at python (and barely more that thing in coding generally), and am quite out of my depth  with this sort of error.  The win32 lines are paticularly baffling, since I am only trying to compile this for a Mac.

PS:  In uase it is relevant, I using python 3.9 and PyCharm to develop  my code. The GUI is entirely dependent on PySimpleGUI, which (I think) has Tkinter underneath it.

Comment: This is a long shot... but it appears you may need xcode installed.

Comment: Well, you were right to surmise that I did not have Xcode installed on my computer.  I do now.  Just isnstalled it.  Should I do something with it?  Cuz jusr trying just rerunning th compile command (.  $ python3 setup.py py2app. ) now the Xcode is installed gave exact the same error result.     Would it help to see my setup.py               script?  Here it is...

Comment: import os

#import ssl

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['zaad4.py']
source_path= os.getcwd()
print(source_path)
dp = source_path + '/data/'
print(dp)
df = []

Comment: import os
from setuptools import setup
APP = ['zaad4.py']
source_path= os.getcwd()
print(source_path)
dp = source_path + '/data/'
print(dp)
df = []
#DATA_FILES = [dp].    setup(
    app=APP,
    py_moddules = ['config', 'ab_fun', 'atom', 'qa_test', 'topics', 'layout',
                   'PySimpleGUI','pkgcsv', 'pkg.re', 'pkg.unicodedata'],
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)

Comment: Standby.  I've got to figure out how this tool formats stuff,  so I can make the code readable.   But... still stuck on my original question.

Comment: 1. Did you restart your computer after installing Xcode? 2. How did you install it? (maybe see [here](https://ma.ttias.be/mac-os-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-missing-xcrun/) - I know its for Git but the problem seems exactly the same)

Comment: Well,  no, I hadn't restarted my Mac  when you asked,  So thanks for that idea too.  But I have now. -   more than once. But no change at all in the behavior and nonchange to the error messages.  Same list of modules it says I need.  I did the reset suggested for Xcode too, that your link suggested.  I would try entering them all in  \my setup file (OPTIONS?), but by the names given, pip doesn't recognize them.  So... I'm more baffled by the day...

Comment: I hope the xcrun issue has at least been solved by installing Xcode. Nonetheless, the unconditional imports listed seem very strange given that it makes no sense to install pywin32 on a mac. I am not really sure how to proceed other than to suggest Pyinstaller instead. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks. You guys who look around the web.  at these qustions from helpless strangers, and then jump right if if you can help are a bun h of heros!    I do appreciate the ideas, even if we haven't gotten to the right answer yet.  ,  I'm thinking I'm probably configured wrong somehow in my virtual evniroment.   Don't know now quite what to change tho.  ..

Comment: I never could figure this out.  So I tried PyInstaller instead, and that seems to work for my code and application.  Thanks again for your time and thoughts this Minion Jim,